# Background Image - Above the fold optimization

Tags: html, css, optimization, pagespeed

Is it possible to load a background image covering the entire website without affecting load speed. I am loading an image in the CSS:

```css
 #wrapper {background-image:url("../images/swirl.jpg");}
```

The wrapper covers my site, so the page is loading and this background-image being loaded is slowing the rest of the CSS, etc being loaded and affecting the performance to what it would be if it was a solid background color or left white.

But I am wondering is there a way to load after the page has loaded or a way around it affecting page load speed?

Answer (score 0):

If you're prepared to use some JavaScript, you can detect when the page has loaded, and only then set the id to load the background image. If the background image is set on the `body` element, this should do the trick (if not, change `body` to be a selector that matches the element you want to apply the background image to):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  document.querySelector('body').setAttribute('id', 'wrapper');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some Thoughts:**

*Will Need to be tested.*

- Optimize the actual image and make sure it's size appropriate (You don't need 5000px worth of image when most screens are only [1366×768](https://techcrunch.com/2012/04/11/move-over-1024x768-the-most-popular-screen-resolution-on-the-web-is-now-1366x768/)).

and/or....

- Use Javascript to set the background-image after the page is done loading.